Why is ‘dissect’ (sometimes) pronounced with the ‘long’ PRICE vowel (the diphthong /ʌɪ/) not the ‘short’ KIT vowel (the monophthong /ɪ/)?
Yes, I’m aware that not everybody pronounces dissect as
/dʌɪˈsɛkt/ ("dye-SEKT"), especially not outside of North
American dialects of English, and that there are definitely
some people who would argue that that’s not “correct”.  The
important thing is that many people do, forming the basis of
this question.

The relevant etymology of to dissect seems to be dis-, a prefix originally from Latin used for negating, expressing a lack of something or meaning ‘apart’ (other uses too); and ‑sect, from Latin secare meaning ‘to cut’.
What surprises me about this is that in every English word I can think of, the prefix dis‑ is pronounced to rhyme with this, such as in words like disdain, disparage, disassociate, and disguise. In fact, I think in Latin it’s pronounced to rhyme with peace, like in this believable example clip I found. I know /i/ ("ee", the FLEECE vowel) to /ɪ/ ("ih", the KIT vowel) is a common way words from Romance languages get naturalized into English, but dissect seems to not fit that pattern at all.
Even the other dis‑ words whose roots start with an s‑ are pronounced rhyming with this; for example, dissociate, dissatisfy, dissent, dissolve, dissuade, and dissonant.  I’ve even looked through a list or two of all dis‑s… words and I couldn’t find any that I’ve heard pronounced like
dye is.
What’s more, one of the most consistent English pronunciation “rules” (patterns) I’m aware of is that doubled consonants should be preceded with a ‘short vowel’; for example, plume and plummet having different vowels.  There are way too many examples of this pattern with words coming from all different origins. Yet dissect seems to be an exception, and a surprising one since exceptions are very rare and most of the other exceptions come from other languages. For example, there’s illegal, which, when some people exaggeratedly stress the word, can sound like /ˌiː ˈliː gəːl/ ("ee-LEE-gull"). If you push the language’s boundaries a bit, konnichiwa has a long o but it’s because romanized Japanese has its own separate practices
for representing language sounds.
Why does dissect seem to be one of the only exceptions of its kind in the language?

I did find several examples of people in the science fields pronouncing the word as /dʌɪˈsɛkt/ ("dye-SEKT"): (1), (2), (3).  For anyone curious, I should warn that because of the nature of the word dissect, all of these videos incidentally feature dead creatures being cut open.

Possibly people learn bisect /baɪˈsɛkt/ in geometry before they learn dissect /dɪˈsɛkt/ in biology, and assume they sound the same apart from the initial consonant leading to /daɪˈsɛkt/.

It might also relate to how it's possible to stress it on the first syllable, whereas the likes of "discuss" are always stressed on the second syllable. But why that is I don't know.

Isn't this the same pattern we see with digress? There too are there two consonants following di- yet sometimes it’s said with a reduced vowel but  other times said with a full diphthong the way it sometimes can be in digest, dilate, dilute, direct, diverge, diverse, divert, divulge.

I have had to get used to /dʌɪˈsɛkt/ over the last 20 years or so. The US influence on the box etc. I doubt dissent and dissuade will go the same way.

In any case,  one doesn't pronounce two s's. di-sect, written as: dissect

@tchrist Not exactly, I'm concerned with the pattern of doubled (identical) consonants immediately preceded by a long vowel, which is what makes dissect surprising to me. Words like digress have two consonants that aren't the same.

@alphabet Well, that's why when I wrote the question I used sound-alike words and didn't try my hand at any IPA transcription. In my English, "dissect" has the same first syllable as "tie", "dye", "rye", "my", but if that's different for others then I'd welcome an edit to use more consistent example words.

@alphabet /ʌɪ/ is how the PRICE vowel is transcribed in dictionaries of British English aimed at native speakers published by Oxford University Press.

Both pronunciations are recorded in the Oxford Dictionary of English, with /dʌɪˈsɛkt/ listed first. But my 1993 Shorter Oxford English Dictionary only gives /dɪˈsɛkt/.  However as a medical student in the UK back in the 1970's, having 2 or 3 sessions of dissecting the human body every week, I can confirm we mostly used /dʌɪˈsɛkt/, or dropped the vowel nearly completely and said /dəˈsɛkt/

It is difficult to determine the extent to which changes in the reported pronunciation of dissect in different editions of Merriam-Webster's Collegiate Dictionary series reflect real-world changes rather than just changes in the dictionary's pronunciation system and/or changes in its openness to a descriptive rather than prescriptive approach to pronunciation.
Nevertheless, it may be of interest to review the changes in pronunciation of the word that have appeared in different editions of the Collegiate Dictionary over the years, starting with the first edition (1898):

Dis-sect (dĭs-sĕkt´) 1. To divide into separate parts, as an animal or plant, for examination and to show the structure and relations of parts; to anatomize. 2. To analyze ; to divide and examine minutely.

The third edition (1916) breaks with the first edition by rejecting its predecessor's pronunciation that includes an s at the end of the first syllable and another s at the beginning of the second syllable:

dis·sect´ (dĭ·sĕkt´), v. t. 1. To divide into separate parts, as an animal or a plant, esp. for examination; to anatomize. 2. To analyze, for purposes of science or criticism.

As recently as the sixth edition (1949), the Collegiate Dictionary presents the pronunciation of dissect that first appeared in the third edition as the only one in approved current use:

dis·sect´ (dĭ·sĕkt´), v. t. 1. To divide into separate parts, as an animal or a plant, for examination; to anatomize. 2. To analyze, esp. critically.

In sharp contrast, the seventh edition (1963), notes three pronunciations in fairly widespread use, none of them precisely the version identified in the third through sixth editions:

dis·sect \dis·'ekt; dī·'sekt, 'dī-,\ vb {L dissectus, pp. of dissecare to cut apart, fr. dis- + secare to cut — more at SAW} vt 1 : to separate into pieces : expose the several parts (as of an animal) for scientific examination 2 : to analyze and interpret minutely ~ vi : to make a dissection

It is surely not coincidental that the Seventh Collegiate was the first edition of the Collegiate Dictionary series to be based on [Merriam-]Webster's Third New International Dictionary, which marked Merriam-Webster's embrace of descriptivism on multiple fronts—presumably including pronunciation.
In any event, the pronunciations that appear in the Seventh Collegiate remain in place in the four subsequent editions, most recently the Eleventh Collegiate (2003). But given that dissect has appeared in English writing since at least 1598, the sixty-year run that dī·'sekt and 'dī·sekt have enjoyed in Merriam-Webster's coverage seems rather brief.
As for why the long-i pronunciation caught on, I think that the suggestions in comments posted by Henry and by tchrist beneath the posted question are on point. From Henry:

Possibly people learn bisect /baɪˈsɛkt/ in geometry before they learn dissect /dɪˈsɛkt/ in biology, and assume they sound the same apart from the initial consonant leading to /daɪˈsɛkt/.

From tchrist:

Isn't this the same pattern we see with digress? There too are there two consonants following di- yet sometimes it’s said with a reduced vowel but other times said with a full diphthong the way it sometimes can be in digest, dilate, dilute, direct, diverge, diverse, divert, divulge.

Although dissect is unique in being spelled normally with a double-s and yet sometimes pronounced with a long-i, Merriam-Webster notes another oddball that sometimes appears as a variant spelling:

di·syl·la·ble also dis·syl·la·ble \ˈdī-ˌsi-lə-bəl, (ˌ)dī-ˈsil-;
ˈdi-ˌsil, (ˌ)di(s)-ˈsil-\ n : a linguistic form consisting of two syllables

The mystery in this case is why a creative speller thought it would make sense to double the s in a word whose original prefix was di- (in the sense of "two").
